# Chrome Packaged App - Always-On-Bottom

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am working on a desktop widget system for Chrome OS, and I would like to have the widgets be able to be only seen when all the windows are minimized (or when the desktop is exposed). I know there is a window option to have the window be alwasyOnTop, but is there a way that I can make the window 'alwaysOnBottom'? Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet, and there doesn't seem to be any plans to add it.

Comment: @DanielHerr Is there any way I can do that with js/jquery?